# Merging multiple datasets with different weights

Tags: r

I am working in R and have 3 datasets which have different weights. I'd like to merge the three datasets and create a new weight variable. I use rbind(t1,t2,t3) to merge the three tables.
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? It isn't clear to me what a weight is in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = data.frame()
df2 = data.frame()

df1 <- c(1,2,3)
df2 <- c(4,5,6)

df1 <- scale(df1, center = F, scale = 3)
df2<- scale(df2, center = F, scale = 3)

df <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

Result:

```
>df
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3333333
[2,] 0.6666667
[3,] 1.0000000
[4,] 1.3333333
[5,] 1.6666667
[6,] 2.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for the response. My question was meant to be more theoretical. Say I have two datasets, each with its own weights, can I merge these two datasets and still be able to use the new weights variable? Or do I have to calculate a new weighting variable? For example, what will be the weighted average of var2 after merging the two tables below: t1 = (id = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(22,33,44), weights = c(0.5,1,1.5)) say t2 = t1

Comment: Typically, weighted ave = (val1*w1 + val2*w2 + ...)/(val1 + val2 + ...) . It should apply to all cases, where two measurements are uncorrelated